# Is there a way to measure time to microseconds precision on Windows?

Tags: c++, c++11

My problem:

1. Receiving broadcast from server.
2. Receiving broadcast from my intermediate layer.

Here I am receiving two broadcasts in a server [UDP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Datagram_Protocol) application within the same millisecond. How do I find the difference between them to microseconds precision?

How can I measure the time at a microseconds precision level?

Answer (score 1):

Use [QueryPerformanceCounter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644904%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It's machine dependent, but most processors run very fast these days, and you'll get better than microsecond accuracy.

Comment: A C++11 wrapper for that is `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock`. Its resolution is usually 100 nanoseconds.

Answer (score 0):

In the 1990s I wrote I program running on [MS-DOS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DOS) which used a product called Personal Computer High Resolution Timing (PCHRT) by a company called Ryle Design, in Mt. Pleasant, Michigan.

Their product provided a library of routines that provided micro-second resolution. It worked beautifully, by interfacing directly with the 8253 or 8254 timing chip found in PCs back in those days.

If you can track down Ryle Design, they may have found a way to provide high resolution timing under Microsoft Windows.

When Windows replaced MS-DOS I had to abandon that product and moved my product into custom hardware using a [microcontroller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microcontroller) to achieve high-resolution timing. I couldn't find a way to get high-resolution timing under Microsoft Windows.

This article, although many years old, may help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163996.aspx

Comment: The MSDN link is (effectively) broken. It redirects to a generic MSDN page.

Comment: Are you kidding me? You suggest directly interfacing with hardware?